# Show only active subcategories

Tags: category, magento2.4, sub-categories

so I'm trying to create a widget that will show my subcategories. I've implemented the code and it works but the problem is that it shows the categories even that are not active.
I need some help or recommendation with trying to fix the logic because I've tried a lot of stuff but can't make it work. Below you can find the code for the logic and the template.
Logic:

```
class SubcategoriesWidget extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'widget/subcategories-widget.phtml';

    private CategoryRepository $categoryRepository;
    private Http $request;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Http $request,
        CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getSubcategories()
    {
        $categoryId = $this->request->getParam('id');
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
        $subCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        foreach ($subCategories as $subCategory) {
            if ($subCategory->hasChildren()) {
                $this->getChildNames();
            }
        }
        return $subCategories;
    }


}
```

And this is the code for the template:

```
<?php if ($subcategories = $block->getSubcategories()): ?>
<?php $lastCategory = end($subcategories)  ?>

<div class="mt-[16px]">
    <?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
    <?php if ($subcategory->getIsActive()): ?>
    <a href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl()?>">
            <?php echo $subcategory->getName() ?>
            <?php if ($subcategory->getId() != $lastCategory->getId()) {
                echo " | " ; } ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Could you confirm the following code is redundant?

```
foreach ($subCategories as $subCategory) {
    if ($subCategory->hasChildren()) {
        $this->getChildNames();
    }
}
```

I've tested your code without the above code, and it works as expected. But due to `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::getChildrenCategories()` method can return object (Collection) or an array, your code has to modify to make it compatible with PHP 8:

Change `<?php $lastCategory = end($subcategories) ?>`

to `<?php $lastCategory = is_object($subcategories) ? $subcategories->getLastItem() : end($subcategories); ?>`

**Finally**, your `SubcategoriesWidget` class should looks like the following:

```
class SubcategoriesWidget extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'widget/subcategories-widget.phtml';

    private CategoryRepository $categoryRepository;
    private Http $request;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Http $request,
        CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getSubcategories()
    {
        $categoryId = $this->request->getParam('id');
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
        return $category->getChildrenCategories();
    }
}
```

Your code in the template should looks like the following:

```
<?php if ($subcategories = $block->getSubcategories()): ?>
<?php $lastCategory = is_object($subcategories) ? $subcategories->getLastItem() : end($subcategories); ?>

<div class="mt-[16px]">
    <?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
    <?php if ($subcategory->getIsActive()): ?>
    <a href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl()?>">
            <?php echo $subcategory->getName() ?>
            <?php if ($subcategory->getId() != $lastCategory->getId()) {
                echo " | " ; } ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```